# How to solve phone format when use this.setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to user input the phone number `1234567888` will change to `1234 567 888`

I try it with `<TextInput />`

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      phoneNumber: '',
    };
  }

      <TextInput 
        style={styles.textInput}
        keyboardType='numeric'
        onChangeText={(tex) => this.adjustPhoneNumber(tex)}
        value={phoneNumber}
        placeholder={'1234 567 888 '}
        autoFocus={true}
        placeholderTextColor='rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.41)'
      />



adjustPhoneNumber = (tex) => {

    let editedPhoneNumber = tex;

    if (tex.length === 4) {
      editedPhoneNumber = tex.concat(' ');
    } else if (tex.length === 8) {
      editedPhoneNumber = tex.concat(' ');
    }

    this.setState({ phoneNumber: editedPhoneNumber });
}
```

When user input the phone is fine first.

But if user click the return button on keyboard, `TextInput` will stuck when `tex.length === 8`

Any one knows how to fix it when I use `this.setState` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the length between old and new vaule, if new less than old should be skip add whitespace action (or remove the last one char) when length equal 4 or 8。

Comment: Thanks for your help. Mark the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're *always* setting the `phoneNumber` to the previous value plus a space, when the `length` is 4 or 8.

You need to check if the `phoneNumber` has already been edited by you, then don't append space.

A crude solution would be this check:

```
if (this.state.phoneNumber !== editedPhoneNumber) {
  this.setState({ phoneNumber: editedPhoneNumber });
} else {
  this.setState({ phoneNumber: tex });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but if I try the code I find that it always `!==`  no matter how first enter or click return button on keyboard.

Comment: compare the length between old and new vaule, if new less than old should be skip add whitespace action (or remove the last one char) when length equal 4 or 8

Comment: Thanks you so much ! Compare the length between new and old is the solution.

Comment: @NickWang Could you write a new answer? You solved it and you should be given the credit for it. I'll delete mine once you do so.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb ha, ok and thany you very much.

Comment: Thanks both of you.